# QuerySet confusion in Django Admin

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin, django-queryset

Very new to Django/Python, and I've hit a brickwall after reading tons of documentation and posts regarding this issue...

So I'm working on a simple Django app that has a SQLlite database/table of Names and E-Mail addresses.  I want to be able to send an e-mail from the admin panel, and use the name and e-mail address from the checkbox I select for a given name/address combo.  The table itself works fine, as I can send the e-mails from other views on my site.

I'm working on making a custom admin action to do so, which I think is the correct way to go about this...

I thought I understood what the queryset argument is for and how it functions, but no matter what I do, I get an `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'` error.  Clearly I have no idea how queryset works in an admin action.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from email_check.models import employeeEmail
from django.template import loader, Context
from django.core.mail import send_mail


class employeeEmail_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'address')
    actions = ['resend_message']

    def resend_message(self, request, queryset):
        for employeeEmail.address in queryset:
            message = loader.get_template('email.txt')
            messageContext = Context({
                'name': queryset.name
            })
            send_mail('Test Subject Line', message.render(messageContext), 'me@test.com', [queryset.address],
                      fail_silently=False)

admin.site.register(employeeEmail, employeeEmail_Admin)
```

I realize this is a bit vague, but basically I'm hoping to figure out how to access the name and address attributes from my `employeeEmail` model/table so I can send emails from the admin panel.  Where I have `queryset.name` and `[queryset.address]`, those are just example placeholders as I've tried numerous different things without success, and I'm guessing I'm nowhere near a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not quite how Python for loops work.  You want something like:

```
    for employee in queryset:
        message = loader.get_template('email.txt')
        messageContext = Context({
            'name': employee.name
        })
        send_mail('Test Subject Line', message.render(messageContext), 'me@test.com', [employee.address],
                  fail_silently=False)
```

The point is that queryset provides multiple instances of your employeeEmail model.  When you run a for loop over the queryset, `employee` gets bound to each of them in sequence.

Comment: **YES!**  This worked perfectly!  I was more confused about how queryset worked, and didn't realize I could use `employeeEmail.name` and `employeeEmail.address` inside my loop/admin action.  Would there be a better way to do this without the for loop?

Comment: You could use send_mass_mail instead of send_mail to save some time, at the cost of higher memory use while building up a tuple of messages.  As long as you need customized messages for each recipient (adding in their name or the like) I don't see a good way to avoid the for loop.  If the message was the same for everyone, you could bulk extract the email addresses by using a values_list query.

Comment: And actually, now that I've checked the source code rather than just the docs, I see that you could use a lazy evaluating generator that returns a tuple in place of the actual tuple of messages with send_mass_mail, so that could save the extra memory.  Except that internally, send_mass_mail creates a list from them anyway.  I guess it still saves you some of the memory, but not as much as I had first thought.